# MSSQL 2012 Enterprise with json functionality from MSSQL 2016

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2016-express

I have server with MS SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Edition, but I would like to use new functionality from MSSQL 2016. If I had express edition that issue would be easy - I could free upgrade my SQL Server to 2016 Express Edition.

Is it possible to free update the SQL Server to use the new functionality? 
If not, I will be forced to install a version EXPRESS 2016 create database and some procedures, link new SQL Server into SQL Server 2012...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no free upgrade path from SQL Server 2012 Enterprise edition to SQL Server 2016